# SDN base repository doesn't query the correct node labels

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Using SDN 4.2, I am trying to define a base repository with generic methods used by other repositories. When doing so, it seems that the generated queries will use the generic type as the node label, instead of using the actual node entity class name for label.

```
public interface BaseGraphRepository<T extends IdNode> extends GraphRepository<T> {
    T findOneById(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

Now let's say I have

```
@Repository
public interface InstrumentRepository extends BaseGraphRepository<Instrument> {
}
```

When querying the InstrumentRepository, the generated query is

```
MATCH (n:`IdNode`) WHERE n.`id` = { `id_0` } WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN p, ID(n)
```

I would have expected that the node label would be "Instrument" instead of "IdNode".

I've tried to use some SpEL to fix it myself, but it seems that SDN doesn't support the following syntax:

```
public interface BaseGraphRepository<T extends IdNode> extends GraphRepository<T> {
    @Query("MATCH (n:#{#entityName}) WHERE n.id = {id} RETURN n")
    T findOneById(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

Any idea how the node label can be queried correctly in the current case?

Comment: This looks like a bug in SDN4. Seems to work fine with Collection<T> return type, but not with T. You should report it here https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH/

Comment: Have you tried using primary indexes with `Neo4jRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>`? http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/#_usage

Comment: Thanks @digx1, using primary indexes worked in this case. I just removed the findOneById() method, and call the usual findOne(String id) instead. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for the time being you can redefine the method in child repository (which arguably defeats the purpose of the BaseGraphRepository, but as I said, it is just a workaround for the bug):

```
public interface InstrumentRepository extends BaseGraphRepository<Instrument> {
    Intrument findOneById(String id);
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I did in the meantime, but as you said, it defeats the purpose of the base class.